# session can't be set in a class function

Tags: php, class, multilingual

I tried to build a multi-language site, but the problem the variable can't be set after clicking the submit button for choosing language:

```
<form action="<?php $aradown->make_lang(); ?>" method="post">
  <input type="submit"  name="en" value="english" >
  <input type="submit" name="ar" value="arabic" >
</form>
```

Class function code:

```
public function make_lang(){
  if($_POST['en']){
    $_SESSION['lang_en'];
  }

  if($_POST['ar']){
    $_SESSION['lang_ar'];   
  } 
}   

public function check_lang(){
  if(isset($_SESSION['lang_en'])){
    $lang="english";
  }
  if(isset($_SESSION['lang_ar'])){
    $lang="arabic";
  }
  $path=dirname(__FILE__)."/languages/".$lang.".php";   
  return $path;
}
```

And this is the code to use:

```
include('includes/core.class.php');
$aradown= new aradown;
$lang_file=$aradown->check_lang();
include($lang_file);
```

I tried to print the result of `$lang_file`, but the `$lang` var is empty.

```
C:\AppServ\www\aradown-new\includes/languages/.php
```

Any thing missing?

Comment: Try it with `session_start();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually set the variables to something.

```
    if($_POST['en']){
        $_SESSION['lang_en'] = true;
        }

    if($_POST['ar']){
        $_SESSION['lang_ar'] = true;   
        }
```

As well as start the session using `session_start()`.

Comment: wow,solved,but why the session variable should be set to true after making it inside a class function bcz this isn't usual to do that

Comment: You weren't setting the variable; you were trying to get it, which should have resulted in a "Notice: Undefined index:" if you had error reporting turned on (and to show notices). If you don't set it then `isset` will return false.

Comment: thanks michael,i understood now,appreciated,and thanks for error reporting notice bcz i didn't do